# Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence with $s_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}{n}$.Show that if $(x_n)$ is converges to $x$, then also $(s_n)$ is.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence with $s_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}{n}, n\ge 1$.
Show that if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then also $(s_n)$ does.

Since $(x_n) \to x$, given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exist $M \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \ge M$, we have $|x_n - x| < \varepsilon$.

To show: $|\frac{x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n}{n} - x| < \varepsilon$.

How to get the approach?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are *not* trying to show |(x_1+...+x_n)/n - x| < .  Instead, you are trying to show that for any  > 0, there exists an integer N > 0 (depending on ) such that  n ≥ N implies that |(x_1+...+x_n)/n - x| <  is true.

Comment: @DanAsimov Cause I do not know how to start since it is the partial sum of $x_k$.

Comment: This must be a duplicate of an existing question on this site....

Comment: As a brief conceptual (hand-waving) summary of the answer referenced by @angryavian : suppose that $M$ is chosen so that for $n \geq M, |x_n - x| < \epsilon/2.$  Further suppose that $|x_1 + \cdots x_M - Mx| = (k+1)\epsilon.$  In effect, you have an *overage* of $k\epsilon.$  Each term $x_n ~: n > M$ results in an *undercut* of $\epsilon/2$.  If you take on an additional $2k$ terms, you will have undercut enough, so that the overall average is now at or below $\epsilon.$  So, you let $M_1 = M + 2k$.  Then, for any $n \geq M_1$ the desired inequality will be produced.

Comment: Solved and I get it right now. Thanks Sir.